# Assign_vertex_id function does not exist

Tags: pgrouting

I would like to add unique start/end nodes for each feature in my road network.  I ran across some posts referencing the pgrouting assign_vertex_id function, which appears to do exactly what I want, but when I try to use it, I get an error saying the function does not exist.

PGRouting is installed and enabled on my database.  Using

```
SELECT pgr_version();
```

I can see that I am running 2.1.0.  Was this function removed at some point, and if so, is there a good alternative in place?

Update, here is the code I am trying to run, where tucson is a table of roads and the geometry is a Linestring

```
ALTER TABLE tucson ADD COLUMN source integer;
ALTER TABLE tucson ADD COLUMN target integer;
SELECT assign_vertex_id('tucson', 0, 'geom', 'gid');
```

And then I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  function assign_vertex_id(unknown, integer, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 3: SELECT assign_vertex_id('tucson', 0, 'geom', 'gid');
           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 4):

I am running pgrouting version 2.0.0, and assign_vertex_id or pgr_assign_vertex_id doesn't exist.

To build the topology, I use the function [pgr_createtopology](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/common/doc/functions/create_topology.html).
 In your case, you could go like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tucson ADD COLUMN source integer;
ALTER TABLE tucson ADD COLUMN target integer;
SELECT pgr_createtopology('tucson', 0.001, 'geom', 'gid', 'source', 'target');
```

It will fill columns source and target in the table 'tucson' and creates a vertices table.

In case you have already created the source and target columns , you can omit those two columns and use pgr_createtopology function.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://ravi.pckl.me/short/pgrouting-assignvertexid-has-been-renamed/

> assign_vertex_id has been renamed to pgr_assign_vertex_id

Can't find much documentation on it, but it's also described in http://themapguyde.blogspot.co.at/2013/04/mapguide-and-pgrouting-shortest-path.html

Comment: Hmm, that function seems to be missing too.  Can anyone confirm whether or not they have it?